# Iterate through form fields in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: forms, field, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to rewrite a sencha touch application from version 1.1 to version 2.

In st 1.1, i'm looping through form fields this way:

```
this.fields.each(function(field) {
     // Code here
}, this);
```

In st 2, this.fields is null. Is there another way to get fields list inside a form panel ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try this

```
var fields = this.getFieldsArray();
Ext.each(fields, function (field) {
       // code here
}, this);
```

or

```
this.getFieldsAsArray().forEach(function(field) {
     // code here
});
```

Comment: Thank you! getFieldsAsArray is what i'm looking for :-)